# Customer Module not working in local codepool

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to make some minor changes in `AccountController.php`.
So I have copy `AccountController.php` from 
`app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php` 
to
`app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`

But it's not working any idea?

Comment: Make sure cache is properly cleared

Comment: change the folder name from `customer` to `Customer/controllers`

Comment: Marius  i guess that magento cannot override any controller  with NameSpace Mage  from local folder..Mean  copy  from  `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers` to `app/code/local/Mage/Customer/controllers`...

Comment: @Arunendra ,You can  check http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/76628/4564   as alternative solution h

Comment: It's seems that now i have to override it by creating custom module for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code will need to look something like...

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <[vendor]_[modulename] before="Mage_Customer">[Vendor]_[ModuleName]</[vendor]_[modulename]>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and your class

app/code/local/[Vendor]/[ModuleName]/controllers/AccountController.php

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php';

class [Vendor]_[Module]_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
    // do code
}
```

As a side note, copying block / model classes in to the local code pool is never a good idea. It increases the pain you will experience when you try to upgrade because there might be changes in those files you would have to copy in.

Comment: It's work, I was forget that controller can't override by copying from core to local.

Answer (score 2):

Copying files to local code pool will only work for blocks, helpers and models. You cannot override controllers using this method since they are not autoloaded like other classes.

follow this question [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53726/copy-core-file-to-app-code-local-mage-cant-overload)

Answer (score 0):

Create Custom module look like this below steps:

Step 1:- Create a file Custom_Module.xml at **app\etc\module\Custom_Module.xml** and add the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_Module>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Custom_Module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Step 2:- Create a file config.xml at **app\code\local\Custom\Module\etc\config.xml** and add the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_Module>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Custom_Module>
  </modules>
  <global>
                <rewrite>        
            <custom_module_customer_accountcontroller>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/customer/account/#]]></from> <!-- Mage_Customer_AccountController  -->
                <to>/module/customer_account/</to> <!-- Custom_Module_Customer_AccountController  -->
            </custom_module_customer_accountcontroller>
                </rewrite>
  </global>
</config>
```

Step 3:- Create a file AccountController.php at **app\code\local\Custom\Module\controllers\Customer\AccountController.php** and add the below code.

```
<?php
require_once "Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php";  
class Custom_Module_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController{
        // here your function
}
```

Hope this helps!